# python - how to open a zip file using wave?

Tags: python, zip, wave

I have a zip file that contains audio files. I want to open one of them using wave.

I want to run this line:

```
wf = wave.open(audio_path, 'rb')
```

only my audio file is part of a zip file. this is the "intended" action:

```
archive = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path, 'r')
wf = wave.archive.open(audio_path, 'rb')
```

how to do it the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this: in-memory, and writing the audio file to disk (I'll use a temporary file to avoid cluttering up the current working directory).

```
##### Process contents of zip to an in-memory file-like object
import io
import zipfile
import wave

bytesio = io.BytesIO()

with zipfile.ZipFile('audiofiles.zip', 'r') as z:
    files = zipfile.ZipFile.infolist(z)
    for file in files:
        if file.filename == "my_audio_file.wav":
            bytesio.write(z.read(file.filename))
            bytesio.seek(0) # return read point to beginning

wf = wave.open(bytesio, "rb")
...
```

Here is just about the same code, modified to use a temp file:

```
import tempfile
import zipfile
import wave

tf = tempfile.TemporaryFile()

with zipfile.ZipFile('audiofiles.zip', 'r') as z:
    files = zipfile.ZipFile.infolist(z)
    for file in files:
        if file.filename == "my_audio_file.wav":
            tf.write(z.read(file.filename))
            tf.seek(0)

wf = wave.open(tf, "rb")
tf.close() # this closes and deletes the temp file, only do this when
           # you're completely done accessing the file
...
```